# 'Router' is imported from both 'package:fluro/src/router.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using **Fluro package** for navigating. Fluro and Flutter are using 'Router'. So their classes merged. How could I fix this?

lib/routers/routers.dart:2:1: Error: 'Router' is imported from both 'package:fluro/src/router.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart'. import 'package:flutter/material.dart'

I faced with that error when upgraded **Flutter to 1.20.0.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
```

with

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Router;
```

in your navigating class that using fluro. So you could use fluro's Router now.

Answer (score 3):

You can alias the Fluro library with the `as` keyword:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
import 'package:fluro/src/router.dart' as Fluro // Alias to avoid conflicts
```

Then use the alias for any class, method or symbol in the imported library:

```dart
var x = Fluro.Router(...)
```